# Hughe .bak file - which SQL software to use?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have recieved a .bak file, which I need to run through some SQL software. My first approach was the free edition (express and studio manager) from **microsoft**. As I understand, this free edition can't handle files in this magnitude; the file is 7.5 GB. Is there any freeware out there which I can use instead? I can perform very basic commands like `SELECT FROM,` `WHERE` and so on; enough to access what I need. My problem is just, that I can't access the data.

Answer (score 2):

Acording to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Express), you can have DB 10 GB.

> Maximum database size of 10 GB per database in SQL Server 2014

[Here is on of the many videos how to do that.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ohYnBr8SYDg)

Comment: I had a very difficult time to download Microsoft SQL Server 2014 for some reason. I settled with 2012. And in this case, I got an error saying the edition was limited.

Comment: Its been 10GB since V2008 R2, whats the exact error message?

Comment: I'll try to re-create the error. Thank you for your comments so far.

Comment: If the backup is 7.5 GB, the full database (after being restored) is probably over 10

Comment: And in this case, - do you have any recommendations?

Comment: There are 180 day evaluation versions of full SQL Server